# Unable to setup dpkg build environment

Tags: dpkg, launchpad

I'm trying to put the following package into launchpad , but i can't really get it work with `dpkg-buildpackage` even on my system:

```
 dpkg-source -b xfce-appmenu-plugin
Subroutine Dpkg::Source::Archive::getcwd redefined at /usr/share/perl/5.12/Exporter.pm line 64.
 at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Source/Archive.pm line 32
dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no orig.tar file found
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b xfce-appmenu-plugin gave error exit status 255
```

What problem could it be , i don't really have to tar this folder right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no orig.tar file found`

This basically means that the build system is unable to find the source code. Are you sure that there is some file like xfce-appmenu-plugin.orig.tar.gz in the folder?

If yes, then you might be experiencing [this problem](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=51479). In this thread, the solution is to use `dh_make --createorig`. Alternatively, you can use`dh_make -f ../xfce-appmenu-plugin.tar.gz`. These will create the correct .orig.tar.gz, which can then be used by dpkg-buildpackage. Here, `xfce-appmenu-plugin.tar.gz` is the original source code in compressed form.

Looking through another source, I found [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=634510) reported against dpkg-dev (Note that it is the same version that is shipped in Oneiric with the latest updates). The solution mentioned here was to rename the .orig.tar.gz to the exact name mentioned in the Changelog.

Comment: Yeah , dh_make --createorig somehow solved my problem , recreated debian/ folder

Comment: I have updated the answer based on what actually helped you.